# Binning custom data based on a unix timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dict of data entries with a UNIX epoch timestamp as the key, and some value (this could be Boolean, int, float, enumerated string). I'm trying to set up a method that takes a start time, end time, and bin size (x minutes, x hours or x days), puts the values in the dict into the array of one of the bins between these times.

Essentially, I'm trying to convert data from the real world measured at a certain time to data occurring on a time-step, starting at time=0 and going until time=T, where the length of the time step can be set when calling the method.

I'm trying to make something along the lines of:

```py
def binTimeSeries(dict, startTime, endTime, timeStep):
 bins = []
 #floor begin time to a timeStep increment
 #ciel end time to a timeStep increment
for key in dict.keys():
 if key > floorStartTime and key < cielEndTime:
  timeDiff = (key - floorStartTime)
  binIndex = floor(timeDiff/timeStep)
  bins[binIndex].append(dict[key])
```

I'm having trouble working out what time format is suitable to do the conversion from UNIX epoch timestamp to, that can handle the `floor`, `ciel` and `modulo` operations given a variable `timeStep` interval, and then how to actually perform those operations. I've searched for this, but am getting confused with the formalisms for `datetime`, `pandas`, and which might be more suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Instead of asking for a bin size (the interval of each bin), I think it makes more sense to ask how many bins you'd like instead. That way you're guaranteed each bin will be the same size (cover the same interval).

In my example below, I generated some fake data, which I called `data`. The start- and end-timestamps I picked arbitrarily, as well as the number of bins. I calculate the difference between the end- and start-timestamps, which I'm calling the `duration` - this yields the total duration between the two timestamps (I realize it's a bit silly to recalculate this value, seeing as how I hardcoded it earlier in the `end_time_stamp` definition, but it's just there for completeness). The `bin_interval` (in seconds) can be calculated by dividing the duration by the number of bins.

I ended up doing everything just using plain old UNIX / POSIX timestamps, without any conversion. However, I will mention that `datetime.datetime` has a method called `fromtimestamp`, which accepts a POSIX timestamp and returns a datetime object populated with the year, month, seconds, etc.

In addition, in my example, all I end up adding to the bins are the keys - just for demonstration - you'll have to modify it to suit your needs.

```
def main():

    import time

    values = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

    data = {time.time() + (offset * 32): value for offset, value in enumerate(values)}

    start_time_stamp = time.time() + 60
    end_time_stamp = start_time_stamp + 75

    number_of_bins = 12

    assert end_time_stamp > start_time_stamp
    duration = end_time_stamp - start_time_stamp

    bin_interval = duration / number_of_bins

    bins = [[] for _ in range(number_of_bins)]

    for key, value in data.items():
        if not (start_time_stamp <= key <= end_time_stamp):
            continue
        for bin_index, current_bin in enumerate(bins):
            if start_time_stamp + (bin_index * bin_interval) <= key < start_time_stamp + ((bin_index + 1) * bin_interval):
                current_bin.append(key)
                break

    print("Original data:")
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, value)

    print(f"\nStart time stamp: {start_time_stamp}")
    print(f"End time stamp: {end_time_stamp}\n")

    print(f"Bin interval: {bin_interval}")
    print("Bins:")
    for current_bin in bins:
        print(current_bin)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Original data:
1573170895.1871762 A
1573170927.1871762 B
1573170959.1871762 C
1573170991.1871762 D
1573171023.1871762 E
1573171055.1871762 F
1573171087.1871762 G

Start time stamp: 1573170955.1871762
End time stamp: 1573171030.1871762

Bin interval: 6.25
Bins:
[1573170959.1871762]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1573170991.1871762]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1573171023.1871762]
[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into it a bit more in a minute, but the base asumption that it might be better to ask how many bins i want and then derive the interval per bin is not applicable in my case. As mentioned, I'm trying to match up real word events to unitless timesteps, because i'm simulating a system that matches a real system. For that simulation to be usefull, I need to specify what a simulation timestep is in real world time, and need to convert real world events at a time to events in a timesteps to make sure results generated by the simulation line up with the real world data